# Is there a way to make a Zend Framework Application to act like Facebook in profile links?

Tags: zend-framework, routes

My accurate question would be, is there any routes that can make possible that when i go

mydomain.com/profilename

it'd be redirect to the profile controllers instead of index, and sitll, if i provide no parameter, he'd load the index page, and even still, if theres a controller by that name, that he'd run that controller instead of searching for a profile...

Pretty much complicated i know, that's why i'm asking for your help, you geniouses! <3

Thanks in advance, Jorge.

Comment: ZF1 or 2? And isn't this a problem you can solve with route priority?

Comment: I don't know route priority, i there any tutorial around? ZF1. Thanks for your time! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZF1 doesn't have route priority as such, but routes are matched LIFO (last in, first out). So as long as you were able to hard code controller names into your routes, and put this after your profile route, you could do something like this:

```
$router->addRoute('profile',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:profilename', array(
        'module' => 'default',
        'controller' => 'profile',
        'action' => 'view'
    ))
);

$router->addRoute('something',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:controller/:action', array(
        'module' => 'default',
        'action' => 'index'
    ), array(
        'controller' => '(foo|bar)' // names of your controllers
    ))
);
```

Alternatively, if this isn't possible, or you want a more robust (but more difficult) solution, I wrote a blog post a while back with a detailed explanation of how to achieve this with a custom route class: http://tfountain.co.uk/blog/2010/9/9/vanity-urls-zend-framework

Comment: I must say, awsome blog post, highly recommended and solved my problem. You own!